# Max characters in generated file in Nginx + PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I have code like

```
include('file.php');
```

which generate a JS code with ~64000 lines with ~110000 characters. If I add some new characters to loop, total file length will be same, but file will be splitted (total number of rows is reduced). I tryed to change `upload_max_filesize / post_max_size` in php.ini and `client_max_body_size` in Nginx but it doesn't help me. Some solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening here please. `include('file.php');` is server-side PHP right?

Comment: It gives data from MySQL DB like `while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){echo $r['data']}`. If I call this file directly - It`s ok, but if included - having problem with characters

Comment: Well we had better see whats in there

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you mean by `Max characters in generated file in Nginx + PHP`? Was this file auto generated or you created it yourself? Also, where are you including this file? Inside another php script or on nginx conf files (doesn't make sense if you are)? Also, if you're including on php it's generating a javascript code where? Are you printing that? Please share some code logic with us. You are most probably running out of memory on php or your encoding is not the same in all php files.